# Can html5 be used front end for an ftp server?

Tags: html, web, ftp

quick question to day. I've done a little digging around on the net and i can't really find a very definitive answer.

Basically, I run my own server on a redundant dual core, 4gb ram 2Tb pc (server1)

And on here, i would like to make an FTP partition. Reason being, i would very much like to be able to transfer files back and forth work, uni and home as i please.

I also run a website from my server which allows me to stream media from my hard drive to any laptop, tablet, desktop, iphone, android.. you name it!

I would LIKE to be able to add a section on my website where by I can log in and access my files as a sort of HTMF5 Front end.

I am aware and know how to create a login with a database which has md5 hash and store cookies to stop un-authorised people accessing my ftp.

Any help or a shove in the right direction would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes it's possible.** but that won't be HTML5 ftp server etc that you mentioned.

You can achieve this by installing a web server on your machine like apache and then make directories public - run Apache on some port and you will be able to access the directory. if your server is running on port 8080, URL will be like: `domain.com:8080` - You can style directory using **[this](http://adamwhitcroft.com/apaxy/)** simple script & make this password protected as well using .htaccess .

---

## osFileManager

The other option is to use some php script. Many commercial scripts are available and as well as open source. i recommend you trying [osFileManager](http://www.osfilemanager.com/index.html) - it has a lot of features like:

- Browse the directory structure
- Create files
- Upload files
- Rename files
- Move files
- Delete files
- Edit files
- Change permissions
- Change password
- Create users

Here is it's installation instructions: http://www.osfilemanager.com/osfilemanager-docs.html

or a paid HTML5 & AJAX based script can be bought for 14$ from here:
http://codecanyon.net/item/file-manager-and-backup-system/5177206

Comment: I'm already running apache and port 80 from memory.. this is how i publish my website, i also have mysql 5.5? installed and php installed too. Thanks for the link, will check it out now!

Comment: What's issue then ? make all folders/directories public in Apache those you wanna access. if you want to access ALL files, then you have to configure ROOT access on your server. p.s VOte UP for answer and mark accepted if i helped you.

Comment: I was wondering if I can directly upload, download, delete and modify files through my browser to affect the ftp directory

Comment: That's also possible. you need to develop the front end yourself for it. or you can buy it for 10-15$ - If you need help in development, start it & ask for help where you get stuck. Here is what you may be looking for: Open source - > http://www.osfilemanager.com/screenshots.html
Commercial: http://codecanyon.net/item/advanced-file-management/61693?ref=Converginec